# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, errno

I am new to using command line and apologize in advance for any confusion.
I am trying to install STAMP but I get an Errno 13 Permission denied as response.

Found existing installation: scipy 0.13.0b1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.

```
Uninstalling scipy-0.13.0b1:
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 687, in install
      requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 730, in uninstall
      paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
      renames(path, new_path)

    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 292, in renames
      shutil.move(old, new)

    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
      os.unlink(src)

  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I know this issue has been covered in depth but I cannot figure out how to apply the answers to my specific problem.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance
TVAN

Comment: What was the exact command you entered?  This isn't a matter of not using `sudo` is it?

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest. You need to `sudo` this, TVAN.

Comment: Just for your information in the event that you are *very* new to command lines, using sudo means: `sudo <insert your command here without the brackets>` which will then prompt you for your password before executing the command you entered.

Comment: I am trying to install STAMP. I am on the last step provided in http://kiwi.cs.dal.ca/Software/Quick_installation_instructions_for_STAMP

Comment: I have now managed to get the script to work so thank you!

Comment: I have tried to open STAMP and get : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/STAMP", line 32, in <module>
    from stamp import STAMP
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stamp/STAMP.py", line 38, in <module>
    from stamp.GUI.plotDlg import PlotDlg  # forward reference so py2app recognizes this file is required
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stamp/GUI/plotDlg.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Comment: I have tried to install PyQt4 both in the command line and online but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pip install STAMP
```

whenever you see the phrase like this:"Permission denied", you should look up for this command.